# How to use NB algorithm for this classifier

Tags: r, naivebayes, classifier4j

I have created the columns 3,4,5 & 6 as vectors i.e. using data$height,... & so on

```
people          built       height   weight  educated  acceptchanges
p1              hillyreg      6       90      True        True
p2              plainsreg     5       80      false       false
p3              mountreg      4       75      true        false
```

The target classifier is column `built` and I need to get a confusion matrix on these 3 categories for built - hilly, plain & mountreg

Comment: Can you edit your question please to show your attempts and describe where you are stuck, including what packages (are you actually using Classifier4J?) / functions you have used.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am closing this questions as I was able to run the algorithm with only features with numbers and I feel a mix of number values + boolean values is not good for my model